# IBM i - CL - pass library and dataarea name as parm(s) into RTVDTAARA

Tags: ibm-midrange

How do I pass library and dataarea name as a parm(s) into RTVDTAARA command in IBM i CL?
Like this operating system is truncating value at 10 characters.

```
 DCL        VAR(&LIB_DTA) TYPE(*CHAR) LEN(21)                
 DCL        VAR(&CPY)   TYPE(*CHAR) LEN(3)   
 
 RTVDTAARA  DTAARA(MYLIB/MYDTA (1 5)) RTNVAR(&DUMMY)   // parm as values works

 CHGVAR     VAR(&LIB_DTA) VALUE('ARDTA' *TCAT &CPY *TCAT '/MYDTAARA')                                  
 RTVDTAARA  DTAARA(&LIB_DTA (1 5)) RTNVAR(&DUMMY)    // but pass as variable does not        
 RTVDTAARA  DTAARA(%TRIM(&DTA)/%TRIM(&LIB)) RTNVAR(&DUMMY)   // ...nor does this
```

Answer (score 2):

use `%scan` and `%sst` built in functions to split the qualified library and dtaara name into two distinct variables.

```
             PGM

             dcl        &vlu  *char 80
             DCL        VAR(&LIB_DTA) TYPE(*CHAR) LEN(21)
             dcl        &fx *int
             dcl        &lx *int
             dcl        &bx *int
             dcl        &name *char 10
             dcl        &lib *char 10

             CHGVAR     VAR(&LIB_DTA) VALUE('*LIBL' *TCAT +
                          '/steve')

/* split qualified library and dtaara name.  */
             chgvar     &fx %scan('/' &lib_dta )
             chgvar     &lx (&fx - 1)
             chgvar     &lib %sst(&lib_dta 1 &lx)
             chgvar     &bx (&fx + 1)
             chgvar     &name %sst(&lib_dta &bx 10)

/* read the dtaara using qualified library and dtaara name.  */
             RTVDTAARA  DTAARA(&LIB/&name) RTNVAR(&vlu)
             sndpgmmsg  &vlu

             endpgm
```